# Could anyone help me to solve the following differential equation?

Tags: differential-equations

I have a problem with the solution of this PDE, how can I start to solve it?

$\left(\partial_x^2 + \frac{1}{x}\partial_x 
+
\partial_y^2 \right) F(x,y) =
\frac{4\pi I}{x} \left(\frac{\sqrt{x^2+(y\pm M)^2}-2M}
{\sqrt{x^2+(y\pm M)^2}+2M}\right)^{1/2}\delta(x-x_0)\delta(y-y_0) $

where $I$ and $M$ are the positive constants.

Comment: unreadable and uncopiable to Mathematica! please copy and paste your mathematica  code you rote to solve the equation. when you paste, each line of your code must start with 4 spaces.

Comment: Are you trying to solve this with the _Mathematica_ software, and if so what have you already tried? If you are only interested in the solution, you may wish to post it on https://math.stackexchange.com/ since this site is specifically for questions regarding the _Mathematica_ software. It is rather unlikely that this PDE has a nice closed form solution regardless, so you may have better luck defining boundary conditions and using numerical methods.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE. Are you sure you are posting on the right site? There is nothing in your question making it clear that it is concerned with Mathematica software.

Comment: I think that he needs some directions on how to solve this D.E using Mathematica. This is what I understand at least.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is probably more mathematical physics than Mathematica, but it is too interesting for me to ignore.  It would help to have some boundary conditions specified in the question, but I will choose some that make the problem doable.  Since we are dealing with Cartesian coords, consider a  rectangular boundary with `0 <=x<=a` and `0 <=y<=b`, with `D[F[x,y],x] = 0` at `x = 0` and `F = 0` on the other boundaries.   We can see that the RHS of the pde is 0 everywhere except at `{x,y} == {x0,y0}`, so we can replace `x` and `y` under the radical with `x0` and `y0`,  which are within the rectangular boundary.
Separate variables for the homogeneous eq only to get the form of the solution.

```
pde = D[F[x, y], x, x] + (1/x)*D[F[x, y], x] + D[F[x, y], y, y] == 
    ((4*Pi*II)/x)*Sqrt[(Sqrt[x^2 + (y + M)^2] - 2*M)/(Sqrt[x^2 + (y + M)^2] + 2*M)]*DiracDelta[x - x0]*
     DiracDelta[y - y0];

F[x_, y_] = X[x] Y[y];

pde[[1]]/F[x, y] == 0 // Expand
(*Derivative[2][X][x]/X[x] + Derivative[1][X][x]/(x*X[x]) + Derivative[2[Y][y]/Y[y] == 0*)
```

The x part and y part must each be separately equal to a constant that could be positive, negative or zero.  I  choose

```
xeq = Derivative[2][X][x]/X[x] + Derivative[1][X][x]/(x*X[x]) == -alpha^2

DSolve[xeq, X[x], x]
{{X[x] -> C[1] BesselJ[0, alpha x] + C[2] BesselY[0, alpha x]}}
```

We won't consider the BesselY since it is not well behaved at x = 0.
We don't really use the above as the solution, but we will use its form to get a solution.
First, expand the `DiracDelta[x-x0]/x` on the RHS of the pde as

```
xddeq = (1/x)*DiracDelta[x - x0] == Sum[An*BesselJ[0, (xn*x)/a], {n, 1, Infinity}];
```

Where `xn` is the nth root of `BesselJ[0,x] = 0`.  This ensures `F = 0` at `x = a`.
We get a warning about no convergence from MMA, but that is the nature of a DiracDelta fn.  From orthogonality solve for `An` by multiplying each side by `x BesselJ[0,(xn x)/a]` and integrating from `0 to a`.

```
$Assumptions = a > 0 && b > 0 && 0 < x0 < a && 0 < y0 < b && xn > 0

Integrate[(1/x)*DiracDelta[x - x0]*x*BesselJ[0, (xn*x)/a], {x, 0, a}] == 
  An*Integrate[x*BesselJ[0, (xn*x)/a]^2, {x, 0, a}]

Solve[%, An] // Flatten;

An = An /. % /. BesselJ[0, xn] -> 0
(*(2*BesselJ[0, (x0*xn)/a])/(a^2*BesselJ[1, xn]^2)*)
```

We used the fact that `xn` is a root of `J0`.
Now

```
xddeq
(*DiracDelta[x - x0]/x == Sum[(2*BesselJ[0, (x*xn)/a]*BesselJ[0,(x0*xn)/a])/
    (a^2*BesselJ[1, xn]^2), {n, 1, Infinity}]*)
```

Now expand `F` as

```
F == (2*Sum[((BesselJ[0, (x*xn)/a]*BesselJ[0, (x0*xn)/a])*f[y])/BesselJ[1, xn]^2, {n, 1, Infinity}])/a^2;
```

Leave out the summation for now to make simplification easier:

```
F[x_, y_] = (2/a^2)*((BesselJ[0, (x*xn)/a]*BesselJ[0, (x0*xn)/a])/BesselJ[1, xn]^2)*f[y]

(pde[[1]] // FullSimplify) == pde[[2]]

% /. BesselJ[0, (x xn)/a] BesselJ[0, (x0 xn)/a] -> a^2/2 BesselJ[1, xn]^2 DiracDelta[x - x0]/x

%/(DiracDelta[x - x0]/x) // Apart
(*Derivative[2][f][y] - (xn^2*f[y])/a^2 == 4*Pi*II*DiracDelta[y - y0]*
   Sqrt[(Sqrt[(M + y)^2 + x^2] - 2*M)/(Sqrt[(M + y)^2 + x^2] + 2*M)]*)
```

The `y` equation becomes

```
fyeq = Derivative[2][f][y] - (xn^2*f[y])/a^2 == 4*Pi*II*DiracDelta[y - y0]*
    (Sqrt[(Sqrt[(M + y)^2 + x^2] - 2*M)/(Sqrt[(M + y)^2 + x^2] + 2*M)] /. {x -> x0, y -> y0})
```

Look at the homogeneous part

```
DSolve[fyeq[[1]] == 0, f[y], y] // Flatten
```

We get exponentials, but for our bc's we need trigs

```
(%[[1, 2]] // ExpToTrig // Simplify) /. {C[1] - C[2] -> A, 
  C[1] + C[2] -> B}
(*A*Sinh[(xn*y)/a] + B*Cosh[(xn*y)/a]*)
```

Use the above to form one function for y < y0, and another for y > y0.
We have to throw the Cosh term out for the fn that includes y = 0.

```
f1[y_] = Sinh[(xn y)/a];
f2[y_] = A Sinh[(xn y)/a] + B Cosh[(xn y)/a];
```

At `y = 0`, `f1[0]==0` is already satisfied, but for `f2` we need `f2[b] == 0`.  Solve for `A` in terms of `B`

```
A = A /. Solve[f2[b] == 0, A][[1]];

f2[y_] = f2[y] // Simplify
(*B*Csch[(b*xn)/a]*Sinh[(xn*(b - y))/a]*)
```

We will form `f[y] = f1[ylesser]*f2[ygreater]` where `ylesser` is the lesser of `y` and `y0` and `ygreater` is the greater of `y` and `y0`.
The discontinuity in slope at `y = y0` equals `D[f[y],y]outer - D[f[y],y]inner` which turns out to be  the Wronskian of the inner and outer functions.  So we have.

```
f1[y] D[f2[y], y] - f2[y] D[f1[y], y] == fyeq[[2]]/DiracDelta[y - y0] // Simplify

B = B /. Solve[%, B][[1]]
```

and

```
f[y_] = f1[ylesser] f2[ygreater] // Simplify
(*-((4*Pi*a*II*Sqrt[(Sqrt[(M + y)^2 + x^2] - 2*M)/(Sqrt[(M + y)^2 + x^2] + 2*M)]*
    Csch[(b*xn)/a]*Sinh[(xn*ylesser)/a]*Sinh[(xn*(b - ygreater))/a])/xn)*)
```

Put everything together adding back the summation we get

```
F[x_, y_] = -4*Pi*a*II*Sqrt[(Sqrt[(M + y0)^2 + x0^2] - 2*M)/(Sqrt[(M + y0)^2 + x0^2] + 2*M)]*(2/a^2)*
   Sum[((BesselJ[0, (x*xn)/a]*BesselJ[0, (x0*xn)/a])/BesselJ[1, xn]^2)*
     ((Csch[(b*xn)/a]*Sinh[(xn*ylesser)/a]*Sinh[(xn*(b - ygreater))/a])/xn), {n, 1, Infinity}]
```

which is the solution.  Plug in some numbers for plotting.

```
a = 1;
b = 2;
II = 1;
M = 1;
x0 = a/5;
y0 = 2 b/3;
```

Get the terms that include ylesser and ygreater into a form that we can plot.

```
g[y_] = Piecewise[{{Sinh[(xn[n] y)/a] Sinh[(xn[n] (b - y0))/a], 
    y <= y0}, {Sinh[(xn[n] y0)/a] Sinh[(xn[n] (b - y))/a], y > y0}}]
```

and xn are the roots of J0

```
xn[n_] = N[BesselJZero[0, n]];
```

For plotting we can define F this way

```
F[x_, y_, m_] := (-(1/a))*8*Pi*II*Sqrt[(Sqrt[(M + y0)^2 + x0^2] - 2*M)/(Sqrt[(M + y0)^2 + x0^2] + 2*M)]*
   Sum[(Csch[(b*xn[n])/a]*BesselJ[0, (x*xn[n])/a]*BesselJ[0, (x0*xn[n])/a]*g[y])/(xn[n]*BesselJ[1, xn[n]]^2), 
    {n, 1, m}]

Plot3D[Evaluate[F[x, y, 100]], {x, 0, a}, {y, 0, b}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "F"}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

and some of the more interesting cross sections

[image]
[image]
[image]

Presumably it would take many more terms to get an accurate value for the discontinuity peak.